# Why my for loop is not working for indexing my JSON URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, dom

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var streamers = ["freecodecamp", "OgamingSC2", "cretetion", "ESL_SC2", "storbeck", "habathcx", "RobotCaleb", "noobs2ninjas"];
  var status;
  for (var i = 0; i < streamers.length; i++) {
    var url = "https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/streams/" + streamers[i];
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
      if (data.stream === null) {
        status = "Offline";
        var url2 = "https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/channels/" + streamers[i] + "";
        $.getJSON(url2, function(data2) {
          $("#container").append('<div class="row"><div class="col-sm-4"><img class="img-circle img-responsive" src="' + data2.logo + '"></div><div class="col-sm-4"><h2>' + data2.name + '</h2><p></div><div class="col-sm-4"><h2>' + status + '</h2></div></div><hr>');
        });
      } else {
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

for loop is not working for indexing my JSON URL. Also Is there any efficient for doing this instead of using two getJSON requests?

Answer (score 0):

Because `$.getJSON(url, function(data) { ...` is asynchronous call and resolves in time that your loop already ended.

Answer (score 0):

The `for`-loop runs to completion before even the first callback gets executed. That means that the first time your inner function is called, the variable `i` is equal to `streamers.length`.

The solution is to make local copies of `i` in a new variable, and use those in the callback. The use of `let` ensures that each variable is a separate copy instead of a reused variable.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var streamers = ["freecodecamp", "OgamingSC2", "cretetion", "ESL_SC2", "storbeck", "habathcx", "RobotCaleb", "noobs2ninjas"];
    var status;
    for(var i = 0; i < streamers.length; i++)
    {
        let j = i; // create local copy to store value of i.
        var url = "https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/streams/" + streamers[j];
        $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
            if(data.stream ===  null) {
                status = "Offline";
                var url2 = "https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/channels/" + streamers[j] + "";
                $.getJSON(url2, function(data2) {
                    $("#container").append('<div class="row"><div class="col-sm-4"><img class="img-circle img-responsive" src="' + data2.logo + '"></div><div class="col-sm-4"><h2>' + data2.name + '</h2><p></div><div class="col-sm-4"><h2>' + status + '</h2></div></div><hr>');
                });
            }
            else
            {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    }   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When your ajax request callback at line 6 execute, the for loop has been end, the value of the global varialbe `url` which you declear using `var` is `urlPrefix + arr[the last index]`, so all ajax in the callback request the same url.

You can read this [doc about closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) to learn why your code run in this way.

Answer (score 0):

Rearrange your code to use `then` instead of a success call back  and try:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var streamers = ["freecodecamp", "OgamingSC2", "cretetion", "ESL_SC2", "storbeck", "habathcx", "RobotCaleb", "noobs2ninjas"];
            var status;
            for (var i = 0; i < streamers.length; i++) {
                var url = "https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/streams/" + streamers[i];

                $.getJSON(url).then(function (data) {
                    if (data.stream === null) {
                        status = "Offline";
                        var url2 = "https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/channels/" + streamers[i] + "";
                        $.getJSON(url2).then(function (data2) {
                            $("#container").append('<div class="row"><div class="col-sm-4"><img class="img-circle img-responsive" src="' + data2.logo + '"></div><div class="col-sm-4"><h2>' + data2.name + '</h2><p></div><div class="col-sm-4"><h2>' + status + '</h2></div></div><hr>');
                        });
                    } else {
                        console.log(data);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```